# what other locations we can access like "user.dir" in Java?

Tags: java, documentation

When I run:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir"));

    }
```

It gives root location of my project. Similarly if I specify `${project.build.outputDirectory}` it gives me location of `/project_root/target` but when I try to access same in main method it fails (gives `null`).

Need some official documentation where list of such directories is list, which can be accessed programmatically via `pom.xml` and via `main` method..

Comment: Pom.xml is a file used by maven, a third party tool. System properties are a part of the java standard library. You won't find anything from Pom.xml in your system properties (although the reverse may be possible)

Comment: You mean I can use "${user.dir}" in pom and it will take me to project root? BTW, where all such notations are listed like `user.dir`, `user.dir.resources` like that, any documentaion, official page for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of system properties that can we use in your project. Some are listed in the official doc. Rest you can get by a small snippet.

```
System.getProperties().entrySet().forEach(e -> {
        System.out.println(e.getKey() + " : " + e.getValue());
    });
```

[Official Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html)

[Blog](http://www.bytefold.com/system-properties-in-java/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the FileHandler

"%t" the system temporary directory
"%h" the value of the "user.home" system property

https://kodejava.org/how-do-i-get-operating-system-temporary-directory-folder/

```
 public class TempDirExample {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
         // This is the property name for accessing OS temporary directory
         // or folder.
         String property = "java.io.tmpdir";

         // Get the temporary directory and print it.
         String tempDir = System.getProperty(property);
         System.out.println("OS temporary directory is " + tempDir);
     }
 }
```

Or you could pass a Directory in via a properties file.